# How can i retrieve individual color components(red,blue,green) from the rgb format using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, colors

$('#selector').css('background-color');

This returns the background color as rgb(xxx,yyy,zzz)

How to get individual color components(red, green, blue) in DECIMAL from this string?

---

The solution:

```
function icolor(rgb){
 rgb = rgb.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);
 var red=parseInt(rgb[1]);
 var green=parseInt(rgb[2]);
 var blue=parseInt(rgb[3]);
```

}

Comment: Why don't you want to use a function? That doesn't really make sense.

Comment: So do you want HEX or decimal?

Comment: Earlier, I was employing bitwise operators on a HEX string to extract individual color components. 
@Pointy, i didn't want convert rgb string to HEX(no issues with using a function)
I have solved the problem, so have edited the question, to make things more clear!

Answer (score 3):

What about getting all numbers, converting them to Hex:

```
function convert(value){
    return(value.match(/\d+/g)).map(function(o){ 
        var val=(o*1).toString(16);
        val=(val.length>1)?val:"0"+val;
        return val;
    }).join("")
}
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/dtm8T/1/) is the fiddle to play with.

with my favourite color: BADA55 ;)

Comment: It is a real `Badass`-Color :D

Comment: @ThomasJunk, as mentioned earlier, this is exactly what i didn't want to do!! Nonetheless, thanks for your effort. :)

Comment: Oh sorry, that was a misunderstanding. You could take out the `toString`-part, though ;)